# Return a struct for a program which calculate the translation

Tags: c, struct, return, translation

I would make a program which calculate the translation of a point by translation vector.
To make this, i want to return my struct to my main:

```
#ifndef _STRUCT_H_
#define _STRUCT_H_

typedef struct s_result
{
  int   result1;
  int   result2;
}       t_result;

#endif /* _STRUCT_H_ */
```

But i have a compile error:

```
Translation.c:15:16: error: return type is an incomplete type
Translation.c: In function ‘my_translation’:
Translation.c:29:3: warning: ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void [enabled by default]
Translation.c: In function ‘main’:
Translation.c:45:12: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

Function:

```
struct  s_trans my_translation(char *av1, char *av2, char *av3, char *av4)
{
  int   x;
  int   y;
  int   tx;
  int   ty;
  t_result      s_trans;

  x = atoi(av1);
  y = atoi(av2);
  tx = atoi(av3);
  ty = atoi(av4);
  s_trans.result1 = x + tx;
  s_trans.result2 = y + ty;
  return (s_trans);
}

int     main(int ac, char **av)
{
  int   i;
  int   j;
  int   trans_tab[2];
  t_result      s_trans;

  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  while (av[j])
    {
      if (av[j] == "T")
        {
          s_trans = my_translation(av[j - 2], av[j - 1], av[j + 1], av[j + 2]);
          printf("Translation de vecteur (%d, %d)", trans_tab[0], trans_tab[1]);
        }
      ++j;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `struct s_trans` instead of `struct t_result` from `my_translation`. Since you have `typedef`ed the struct already, you can omit `struct` when declaring the return type and simply return `t_result`.